# Pine Script variable scope

Tags: scope, pine-script

I'm writing a simple strategy using inside bars. The issue I have is that I would like to cancel a trade if the high of any bar after the entry candle goes above the inside bar high.

The snippet of code below should hopefully explain it a little better

```
var short_Stop_Loss_Level = 0
if (high[0] > short_Stop_Loss_Level)
    label.new(bar_index, high, style=label.style_none, text="C=" + tostring(short_Stop_Loss_Level), yloc=yloc.abovebar)
    strategy.cancel_all()


Short_Condition = t and Inside_Bar
if Short_Condition
    short_Stop_Loss_Level = high[0] + 0.03

    label.new(bar_index, low, style=label.style_none,
          text="s=" + tostring(short_Stop_Loss_Level), yloc=yloc.belowbar)

    strategy.cancel_all()
    // strategy.close_all()
    strategy.entry("Enter", strategy.short, stop=Short_Stop_Buy_Level, qty=100)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQcA1.png)

From the pic you can see the stop value is not being maintained outside the if scope, even though I've declared a global stop variable. I'm fairly new to this maybe i'm making a simple mistake that I can't spot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `pine-script`, [variable declaration](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#variable-declaration) is done with the `=` operator. Just like you did like `var short_Stop_Loss_Level = 0`.

However, [variable assignment](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#variable-assignment) is done with the `:=` operator. So, whenever you want to give a new value to an ***already defined*** variable, you should use the `:=` operator.

```
if Short_Condition
    short_Stop_Loss_Level := high[0] + 0.03
```

You should double check your code and make sure you use the `:=` operator, whenever it is needed.